# Autodesk Forge C# Issue Creation API Error, AUTH-010

Tags: autodesk-forge

I'm testing the issue-creation-code(origin: [forge-checkmodels-createissues-revit/web/Controllers/BIM360.cs](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-checkmodels-createissues-revit/blob/master/web/Controllers/BIM360.cs)).
I got an error message below.

My question is two.

1. What is errorCode: `AUTH-010` which is not explained at [developers_guide error_handling](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/developers_guide/error_handling/).
   I checked settings "Permission Level was set to Full Control" that are on BIM 360 Project Admin Services' Issues menu, and I could not guess about suspicious "Token does not have the privilege for this request".
2. Would you suggest Github's sample code? Or advise me additional code check.

Thanks in advance.

{"Request":{"UserState":null,"AllowedDecompressionMethods":[0,2,1],"AlwaysMultipartFormData":false,"JsonSerializer":{"DateFormat":null,"RootElement":null,"Namespace":null,"ContentType":"application/json"},"XmlSerializer":{"RootElement":null,"Namespace":null,"DateFormat":null,"ContentType":"text/xml"},"ResponseWriter":null,"UseDefaultCredentials":false,"Parameters":[{"Name":"Authorization","Value":"Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Imp3dF9zeW1tZXRyaWNfa2V5In0.eyJ1c2VyaWQiOiJVMzlKSldYTlhGOUoiLCJleHAiOjE1ODM5MTc2ODYsInNjb3BlIjpbImRhdGE6cmVhZCJdLCJjbGllbnRfaWQiOiJidmlheEd0R3BFd1pGcWw1dkpsb2k4SUF4a1E0Ym9YRSIsImdyYW50X2lkIjoia0h3R1FWRXZXU3g4MUlvOVFuWU5UdkdjRU94NjBFaWkiLCJhdWQiOiJodHRwczovL2F1dG9kZXNrLmNvbS9hdWQvand0ZXhwNjAiLCJqdGkiOiJFTnFEcmZwaUo0eFdKQm9lNm1DZUV1RFVlZ2VuT2FIUnlPRUpNR3h1UExjakwzYW1nTjRBQ2RTOEdST3Q3NTlLIn0.1VYYXE2ZXcV6Qr2PiGJqMIZNY-Rr2D3EngBVYEcqiXc","Type":3,"ContentType":null},{"Name":"Content-Type","Value":"application/vnd.api+json","Type":3,"ContentType":null},{"Name":"container_id","Value":"45b8e606-f4e3-4233-a508-cbfb0098d28a","Type":2,"ContentType":null},{"Name":"text/json","Value":"{\"data\":{\"type\":\"issues\",\"attributes\":{\"title\":\"이슈생성 API 테스트-1\",\"description\":\"이슈생성 API 테스트-1(나는 내용입니다.)\",\"status\":\"open\",\"starting_version\":\"1\",\"target_urn\":\"1\",\"due_date\":\"2020-03-12T01:19:54.861Z\",\"assigned_to\":\"U39JJWXNXF9J\",\"owner\":\"U39JJWXNXF9J\"}}}","Type":4,"ContentType":null},{"Name":"Accept","Value":"application/json, application/xml, text/json, text/x-json, text/javascript, text/xml","Type":3,"ContentType":null}],"Files":[],"Method":1,"Resource":"/issues/v1/containers/{container_id}/quality-issues","RequestFormat":1,"RootElement":null,"OnBeforeDeserialization":{"Method":{"Name":"<.ctor>b__1_0","AssemblyName":"RestSharp, Version=106.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=598062e77f915f75","ClassName":"RestSharp.RestRequest+<>c","Signature":"Void <.ctor>b__1_0(RestSharp.IRestResponse)","Signature2":"System.Void <.ctor>b__1_0(RestSharp.IRestResponse)","MemberType":8,"GenericArguments":null},"Target":{}},"DateFormat":null,"XmlNamespace":null,"Credentials":null,"Timeout":0,"ReadWriteTimeout":0,"Attempts":0},"ContentType":"application/json","ContentLength":192,"ContentEncoding":"","Content":"{ \"developerMessage\":\"

> `Token does not have the privilege for this request.`

\", \"moreInfo\": \"https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/developers_guide/error_handling/\", \

> `"errorCode\": \"AUTH-010\"`

}","StatusCode":403,"IsSuccessful":false,"StatusDescription":"Forbidden","RawBytes":"eyAiZGV2ZWxvcGVyTWVzc2FnZSI6IlRva2VuIGRvZXMgbm90IGhhdmUgdGhlIHByaXZpbGVnZSBmb3IgdGhpcyByZXF1ZXN0LiIsICJtb3JlSW5mbyI6ICJodHRwczovL2ZvcmdlLmF1dG9kZXNrLmNvbS9lbi9kb2NzL29hdXRoL3YyL2RldmVsb3BlcnNfZ3VpZGUvZXJyb3JfaGFuZGxpbmcvIiwgImVycm9yQ29kZSI6ICJBVVRILTAxMCJ9","ResponseUri":"https://developer.api.autodesk.com/issues/v1/containers/45b8e606-f4e3-4233-a508-cbfb0098d28a/quality-issues","Server":"","Cookies":[],"Headers":[{"Name":"Access-Control-Allow-Credentials","Value":"true","Type":3,"ContentType":null},{"Name":"Access-Control-Allow-Headers","Value":"Content-Length,x-ads-ul-ctx-client-id,x-ads-ul-ctx-caller-span-id,Content-Range,Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Authorization,x-ads-test,x-ads-ul-ctx-oxygen-id,x-ads-acm-scopes,x-ads-ul-ctx-head-span-id,If-Match,x-ads-ul-ctx-source,Accept-Encoding,If-Modified-Since,x-ads-acm-namespace,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials,x-ads-acm-groups,Session-Id,Content-Encoding,x-ads-ul-ctx-scope,Range,Accept,x-ads-ul-ctx-workflow-id,x-requested-with,Expect,x-ads-acm-check-groups,If-None-Match,Content-Type,x-csrf-token","Type":3,"ContentType":null},{"Name":"Access-Control-Allow-Methods","Value":"POST,GET,OPTIONS,HEAD,PUT,DELETE,PATCH","Type":3,"ContentType":null},{"Name":"Access-Control-Allow-Origin","Value":"","Type":3,"ContentType":null},{"Name":"Strict-Transport-Security","Value":"max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains","Type":3,"ContentType":null},{"Name":"Connection","Value":"keep-alive","Type":3,"ContentType":null},{"Name":"Content-Length","Value":"192","Type":3,"ContentType":null},{"Name":"Content-Type","Value":"application/json","Type":3,"ContentType":null},{"Name":"Date","Value":"Wed, 11 Mar 2020 08:59:54 GMT","Type":3,"ContentType":null}],"ResponseStatus":1,"ErrorMessage":null,"ErrorException":null,"ProtocolVersion":{"_Major":1,"_Minor":1,"_Build":-1,"_Revision":-1}}

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/forge/bim360/token/{tokenId}/container/{containerId}/item/{itemId}/version/{versionId}/title/{titleId}/description/{descriptionText}")]
    public async Task<IRestResponse> CreateDocumentIssueAsync(string tokenId, string containerId, string itemId, string versionId, string titleId, string descriptionText)
    {
        dynamic body = new JObject();
        body.data = new JObject();
        body.data.type = "issues";
        body.data.attributes = new JObject();
        body.data.attributes.title = titleId;
        body.data.attributes.description = descriptionText;
        body.data.attributes.status = "open";
        body.data.attributes.starting_version = versionId;
        body.data.attributes.target_urn = itemId;

        //Added by me for test attributes
        body.data.attributes.due_date = "2020-03-12T01:19:54.861Z";
        body.data.attributes.assigned_to = "U39JJWXNXF9J";
        body.data.attributes.owner = "U39JJWXNXF9J";
        //body.data.attributes.ng_issue_subtype_id = "";
        //body.data.attributes.ng_issue_type_id = "";
        //body.data.attributes.root_cause_id = "";
        //body.data.attributes.starting_version = "";
        //body.data.attributes.location_description = "Kitchen";

        //body.data.attributes.pushpin_attributes = new JObject();
        //body.data.attributes.pushpin_attributes.object_id = dbId;
        //body.data.attributes.pushpin_attributes.type = "TwoDVectorPushpin";
        //body.data.attributes.pushpin_attributes.created_doc_version = version;

        RestClient client = new RestClient(BASE_URL);
        RestRequest request = new RestRequest("/issues/v1/containers/{container_id}/quality-issues", RestSharp.Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + tokenId);
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/vnd.api+json");
        request.AddParameter("container_id", containerId, ParameterType.UrlSegment);
        request.AddParameter("text/json", Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body), ParameterType.RequestBody);

        var res = await client.ExecuteTaskAsync(request);

        return res;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check that:

1. Have [access to the BIM 360 account](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/tutorials/getting-started/get-access-to-account/), which I believe you do
2. `data:read` and `data:write` scopes when creating the access token
3. Enabled BIM 360 API when creating the app

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coding their app using Node, there are quite a few errors on the model derivative api example and the design automation api example that will yield the AUTH-010 even if the scopes are set correctly.

On the [execute work item section](https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/designautomation/workitem/nodejs) of the Design Automation Node.js tutorial, we are given this line:

```
await new ForgeAPI.ObjectsApi().copyTo(bucketKey, inputFileNameOSS, outputFileNameOSS, req.oauth_client, req.oauth_token);
```

[Earlier in the tutorial](https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/designautomation/appbundle/nodejs), the parameter req.oauth_client is defined the return value of the `getCredentials()` method on the `AuthClientTwoLegged` object. The result of calling copyTo for me was the mysterious `AUTH-010` code, and I still had the correct scopes defined.

## Solution

I had to substitute the `req.oauth_client` with the actual client_id of my application. This worked for both the Model Derivative API as well as the Design Automation Api.

Unfortunately the [docs for the copyTo function](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-nodejs-client/blob/408551fe4737b2321577329b505e29cdafaa13c8/docs/ObjectsApi.md#copyto) *incorrectly list the parameter as an oAuth2Client type*, which is not the case; anyone getting the error is left guessing what the parameter is since since the docs don't bother to explain each parameter type.

Documentation is disappointing and quite a few errors and typos on both the github documentation and the npm documentation - be prepared to spend a lot of time cross-checking between the Postman tutorials, the utilities like oss-manager, and the error-ridden docs.